# Views message size in email

Tags: mail.app, software-recommendation, ipados

All I want to do is find out how big email messages are. (Curiously enough, I'm having the same challenge with Gmail, but that's another story.) It's obviously a fundamental datum for cleaning up one's mailbox.

Do any mail clients for iPadOS or web services offer this sorting function that I can manage from my iPad ?

Comment: Paul. Software recommendations are on topic. We ask you document specific search. Show the term you searched, the results you chose and detail _ehy_ that answer fails you. A “I googled” without specifics of the term and results you dismissed is worse than showing no research. I think this is clear enough to answer without further edits.

Comment: Also, it’s always the attachments. If you convert mail into plain text, you could store 50 years of email easily on most free cloud tiers.

Comment: Thanks, @bmike. I've tried various strings, including "show email message size ipad" with and without filtering for the iPad community. The searches return posts about a **max** size for messages, or about **font** sizes in messages, or things that don't seem to mention the word _size_ at all.